# Hash duplication not working in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get two separate hashes from one hash in the following code. `s` is a hash initialized with some value in advance. I want to multiply `sheets[:bar]` by `100`.

```
sheets[:foo] = Hash[s.clone.sort_by { |key,value| 
                                      value[:a].to_f.abs
                                    }]

sheets[:bar] = Hash[s.clone.sort_by { |key,value| 
                                      value[:a].to_f.abs
                                    }.reverse.first(20)]

sheets[:bar].each do |k, v|
  v.each do |k1, v1|
    if k1 == "%" then
      sheets[:bar][k][k1] *= 100.0
    end
  end
end
```

Result: Not only in `sheets[:bar]` but also in `sheets[:foo]`, my 20 first values are multiplied by `100`. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Comment: I edited the question but anyway, the type of `s` is obvious (`sort_by |key, value|`)

Comment: It might be obvious, but the code is not runnable, nevertheless.

Comment: Like in 90% of the code in this website. Also, my comment was not for you but the comment I was anwsering to was deleted.

Comment: If all questions contained runnable example, more (all?) of them would be answered. For example, when I can't copy/paste/run the code and the problem/answer is not obvious, sometimes I ask for clarification. But more often I just close the tab. It's in one's best interests to post an sscce. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `.clone` produces a shallow copy of your values in `s`.

Getting a deep copy of an object isn't something Ruby does by default but you would have to use the Marshal module.

```
cloned_hash = Marshal::load(Marshal.dump(s))
```

Comment: Solved with `deep_dup` Thanks.

Comment: Also note that `deep_dup` is an extension of Rails/ActiveSupport and is not part of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Marshal to create a deep copy.

```
foo = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
bar = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
```